# Call a Javascript function AFTER the Server Onclick event

Tags: javascript

I have this code for a click event of a button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "";
    //Series of codes to change the message variable

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "", "ShowMessage(" + message +");", true);
    }



<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowMessage(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
</script>
```

and this won't display the message. maybe my RegisterStartupScript is incorrect?

Comment: We need to see the javascript implementation as well.

Comment: Where is `ShowMessage` defined? Maybe you mean `alert`?

Comment: Make sure that your ShowMessage function is declared globally and not under any other function or callback. also make sure you have this function at the top of the body or under header tag to avoid any loading related issues. Try alerting in the script itself.. Plese use quotes in the function call "ShowMessage('" + message + "');"

Comment: hi @lightstyle, i have alert on my ShowMessage function, but i will need to add some more codes inside ShowMessage function, right now i just want to atleast make sure that the ShowMessage function is being called, the ShowMessage is defined on my .aspx page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try followings,

1. You have to give a valid name for your script. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

   > A startup script is uniquely identified by its key and its type.
   >   Scripts with the same key and type are considered duplicates. Only one
   >   script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page.
   >   Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not
   >   create a duplicate of the script.
2. `ShowMessage` should be defined in the page
3. You have to pass the parameter as string. `ShowMessage('" + message +"');`
4. Final code should like this

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myAlertScript", "ShowMessage('" + message +"');", true);`

***UPDATE***

---

If you have update panels in the page, try following code instead.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,typeof(Page),"myAlertScript","ShowMessage('" + message +"');", true);
```

Comment: hi, right now as you suggested, i've tried this without any luck "Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myTestScript", "alert('test');", true);"

Comment: yes i have some update panels, but the Button1 is outside those update panels, would it affect it? but still i'm gonna try the code you suggested :)

Comment: finally! amazingly it worked! so even if the button is outside the update panel, as long as there is an update panel on the page, it need to use "ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock" instead of "Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript", thanks so much! @ChamikaS

Answer (score 2):

You're missing quotes from around your `message` variable in your call to `ShowMessage`, try this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "ShowMessage(\"" + message + "\");", true);
```

Comment: hi Sean, thanks for this, as @ZebR 's suggestion, i've tried "Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('test');", true);" but it never even displayed the message

Comment: That's strange, have you tried adding a script key as @ChamikaSandamal suggested? That may be what's missing here.

Comment: yes, right now my script  is this "Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myTestScript", "alert('test');", true);" but still the same

Comment: Do you have any script errors in your browser console? Can you view the source of the page and verify that your script has actually been output to the HTML?

Comment: hmmm, you're right! my script hasn't been output to the HTML, there are no errors on my browser console though..

Comment: That's really strange. What else happens on your page when you click the button?

Comment: hmm.. ok here is what happens, inside my Button1_Click event, i am hiding and unhiding some controls and calling the myUpdatePanel.Update(), then that's when i want to call the javascript function, after those codes, but take note that my button is outside the update 'myUpdatePanel', should it affect it?

Comment: If your button is causing a full postback rather than a partial postback (which is what buttons inside UpdatePanels do) then it should be fine, does this happen?

Comment: i've recheck it just to be sure and yes, it's causing a full postback, this is reeeeeaaaaaly strange

Answer (score 0):

To test if the message is delivered to the client you can simply call a native javascript function that'll rule out any client side issues.

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "", "alert('here?');", true);`

You can also view the source of a page in your browser to see if the code is being delivered to the client.

Comment: thanks @ZebR, and it never even displayed the message when i tried this, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To execute code *after* the click handler (and anything it calls) is complete, [set a timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) during the handler.

```
function onClick() {
    window.setTimeout(functionToCall, 0);
}
```